# Recent Changes in Rust Lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've been building a websocket server library with Rust for about 4-6 weeks now.  Today, I grabbed the latest `rustc` using the `rustup.sh` script, and build is breaking from new lifetime requirements.  I'm not sure where to look for these changes to figure out what I need to specify in order to meet the requirements?  [This Week in Rust](http://this-week-in-rust.org/) doesn't have a listing for the recent changes, and the [Lifetimes Guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-lifetimes.html) only goes so far with various examples.

**Various Struct Definitions**

```
pub struct Server<'a> {
    pub sockets: Vec<Socket<'a>>,
    pub events: Vec<Event<'a>>,
    pub to_event_loop: Sender<Action<'a>>,
    pub socket_id: String
}

impl<'a> Clone for Server<'a> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Server<'a> {
        Server {
            sockets: self.sockets.clone(),
            events: self.events.clone(),
            to_event_loop: self.to_event_loop.clone(),
            socket_id: self.socket_id.clone()
        }
    }
}

pub struct Action<'a> {
    pub event: String,
    pub socket: Socket<'a>,
    pub message: Message
}

pub struct Event<'a> {
    pub name: String,
    pub execute: fn(data: json::Json, server: super::Server)
}

pub struct Socket<'a> {
    pub id: String,
    pub stream: TcpStream
}
```

**Function Producing Error**

```
pub fn start(server: Server, ip: &str, port: u16) {

    /*
     * Communication channel
     *     - From HTTP Server to Event Loop (Action Passed)
     */
    let (to_event_loop, from_conn_pool): (Sender<Action>, Receiver<Action>) = channel();

    // Start up event loop
    let server_clone = server.clone();
    let to_event_loop_clone = to_event_loop.clone();
    spawn(proc() {
        event_loop(server_clone, from_conn_pool, to_event_loop_clone)
    });

    // Start TCP server
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(ip, port);
    let mut acceptor = listener.listen();
    for stream in acceptor.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                let event_loop_msgr = to_event_loop.clone();
                spawn(proc() {                
                    process_new_connection(stream, event_loop_msgr)
                })
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error accepting connection: {}", e)
            }            
        }
    }
    drop(acceptor);
}
```

**Compiler Output**

```
src/rustic_io.rs:47:24: 47:30 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
src/rustic_io.rs:47     let server_clone = server.clone();
                                           ^~~~~~
src/rustic_io.rs:50:9: 50:70 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the call at 50:8...
src/rustic_io.rs:50         event_loop(server_clone, from_conn_pool, to_event_loop_clone)
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/rustic_io.rs:50:20: 50:32 note: ...so that argument is valid for the call
src/rustic_io.rs:50         event_loop(server_clone, from_conn_pool, to_event_loop_clone)
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/rustic_io.rs:38:51: 70:2 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 38:50...
src/rustic_io.rs:38 pub fn start(server: Server, ip: &str, port: u16) {
src/rustic_io.rs:39 
src/rustic_io.rs:40     /*
src/rustic_io.rs:41      * Communication channel
src/rustic_io.rs:42      *     - From HTTP Server to Event Loop (Action Passed)
src/rustic_io.rs:43      */
                    ...
src/rustic_io.rs:47:24: 47:30 note: ...so that types are compatible (expected `&server::Server<'_>`, found `&server::Server<'_>`)
src/rustic_io.rs:47     let server_clone = server.clone();
                                           ^~~~~~
```

The compiler is very specific on what the problem is, I just have no idea what syntax it is expecting so that I can satisfy the requirements?

Comment: Can you show us the Socket, Event and Action definitions?

Comment: Looks like your `clone()` method is having lifetime issues, does it really do a deep cloning of your `Server` object ?

Comment: Added extra definitions for various structs and the clone method I implemented (Assuming that is the proper way to do a clone?)

Comment: All the lifetime annotations, ie. <'a>, in Server and its children are redundant, unless Message contains a reference and you forgot to annotate a lifetime for Message. They could be confusing Rust, so try without them. Also try deriving Clone for Server.

Comment: @A.B. Removing all the lifetime annotations worked.  Thanks!